# Calculating Elliptical Orbit in OpenGL?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl

As everyone knows, satellites around the earth don't go in a perfect circle.  They are more an elliptical orbit.

I'm trying to represent this using OpenGL to draw an orbit around the earth.  Currently, I draw a dashed-line composed of 360 markers which makes a series of dashes around the globe in a nice perfect circle.

If I have the Orbital inclination, Perigee and Apogee what would be the way to calculate this circle?  I'm trying to find a formula or white paper or something to get me in the right direction....

Answer (score 3):

What this is crazy, of course they are `perfect` orbits.  No but seriously sounds more like a need Physics formua.  Try..

http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Orbit.html

or

http://physics.info/orbital-mechanics-1/

Comment: Looking @ http://physics.info/orbital-mechanics-1/ now.  I think this is exactly what I need.  Thank God someone knows Math, I was told there would be no math.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have really any experience here, but if you plan to actually track satellites you will want to use the Keplerian elements ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements#Keplerian_elements , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements#Orbit_prediction) which get published for satellites. Note that real satellites have perturbation in their orbits so the Keplerian elements for a satellite are regularly updated. If you just need something that "looks" like satellite orbits then the idealized ellipses form the other answer will be fine.